# AJAX PHP combination returning empty string to the JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an AJAX request to fetch the data from MySQL. On request the `result` variable in the success part contains an empty string, `""`. If I change the dataType to `json` I don't get any results in return.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

```php
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'tabel_name'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>
```

What could be the reason for this empty string as a result? I have data in the table and I don't get any exceptions.

Comment: You have to `echo` the results.....;) Question seems to me a bit too broad to answer as you have to do several things here. Make connection, select db create query get results and ***echo the encoded results*** at php. Now use dataType json at the front end.

Comment: What you echo/display in test.php will be the data that will show up in your `alert()`

Comment: I'd suggest `echo json_encode($result)`

Answer (score 0):

In your php code

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    $sql="SELECT * FROM 'tabel_name'";

    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $resultant_array = array();
    $index = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        foreach($row as $column => $val) {
           $result[$index][$column] = $val;
        }
        $index++;
    }
    echo json_ecode($resultant_array);
    ?>
```

This way you will get response data within your success promise of ajax